# Qual a origem e o significado da frase «levantaram a lebre»?

Tags: etimologia, frases

Li recentemente em uma postagem no [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44686/3635) a frase:

> Já que *levantaram a lebre* sobre multibyte, vou deixar uma alternativa com tal suporte:

Isto me soa como sendo o equivalente a:

> Já que tocaram no assunto sobre ...

Nunca tinha ouvido tal frase, no entanto ao pesquisar notei que de fato ela **não** é incomum.

Gostaria de saber a sua origem, ou se é um termo regional. Também gostaria de saber se o significado é este mesmo ou se pode significar algo a mais ou relativamente diferente.

Answer (score 2):

Eu já conhecia a expressão ***levantar a lebre***, que é relativamente comum em Portugal. Também já vi que também é usada no Brasil (ver comentários), mas só a encontrei em dicionários portugueses. Encontrei a explicação da sua origem em dicionários do século XIX. Literalmente, ***levantar a caça*** significa fazer o animal sair de onde está escondido, para depois o poderem perseguir e matar. Então figuradamente, ***levantar a lebre*** significa “chamar a atenção para um problema imprevisto” [(Infopédia)](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/lebre), que ninguém ainda tinha visto, tal como a lebre literal antes de ser levantada na caça.. Vejamos o dicionário de Morais Silva de 1831, o primeiro onde encontrei a aceção figurada:

[image]
[António de Moraes Silva, *Diccionario da Lingua Portugueza*, Tomo II, 1831, p. 229.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=20ZDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA229&lpg=PA229&dq=%22excitar%20primeiro%20a%20d%C3%BAvida%22&source=bl&ots=v5RqOiRdq5&sig=KFCuZhmMpW83XpL34cvGj8ES9Uo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq59Gmt_TaAhXIsxQKHf4kAosQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22excitar%20primeiro%20a%20d%C3%BAvida%22&f=false)

Eu li a *thread* onde empregaram a expressão —[“levantaram a lebre sobre *multibyte*”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44686/3635)—mas não consegui perceber se a expressão foi usada no sentido tradicional. Até porque os falantes vão variando ligeiramente o sentido em que empregam uma expressão. As definições do Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa de 2001 estão de acordo com a minha experiência pessoal:

> **lebre** […] **levantar a lebre**. *Fam.* 1. Suscitar uma questão, ser o primeiro a descobrir um facto ou uma irregularidade. 2 Chamar a atenção para um problema ou dificuldade inesperada e, em geral, desagradável, visando desviar as atenções.

A expressão figurada é muito antiga, pois por volta de 1610 já Diogo Couto (1542-1616) põe o soldado a responder ao fidalgo, “Vossa Mercê é que alevanta a lebre para eu correr” [(*Soldado Prático*, edição de 1937, p. 29)](http://purl.pt/29284/3/#/62). Não tenho a certeza, mas pelo contexto parece-me que o soldado quer dizer, “Vossa mercê lançou esse assunto para eu discorrer sobre ele”.

“*Correr*” é aqui também uma metáfora da caça à lebre. Na caça, depois de se levantar a lebre, “corre-se a lebre”, isto é, persegue-se a lebre. O Moraes Silva explica:

[image]
[António de Moraes Silva, *Diccionario da Lingua Portugueza*, Tomo I, 1858, p. 559.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=KXLlRqBwZ90C&pg=PA559&dq=%22correr%20a%20lebre%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbqMa22PTaAhVDiqQKHYpyCjkQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22correr%20a%20lebre%22&f=false)

Daí que [*lebre corrida* (Infopédia)](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/lebre) signifique também ‘assunto arrumado’. Este e o *correr a lebre*, eu não conhecia.

Comment: Bom, como fui eu quem escreveu, como brasileiro posso dizer que é conhecido aqui sim. Talvez apenas para os fósseis como eu, mas enfim... XD

Comment: @Bruno, :) Eu fui lá, e vi dois brasileiros dizerem que não conheciam... nem me lembrei de ir ver de onde eras, e presumi erradamente que eras português. Então poderias ter dito, "já que outros levantaram a lebre, agora vou eu também corrê-la!"

Comment: @Jacinto pode ser regional, o Brasil é um país grande, com grandes diferenças culturais internas e até com "idiomas" por região (variações do idioma e até palavras por região, que geralmente são desconhecidas).

Comment: @Bruno, eu não consegui acompanhar completamente a discussão naquela thread. Então com "levantaram a lebre sobre multibyte" queres dizer, como sugeriu o Guilherme, "tocaram no assunto do multibyte"? Eu estou mais habituado a usos como este, ["Quem levantou a lebre foi Gilmar Mendes"](http://nossapolitica.net/2017/02/camara-suspeita-de-fraude/), que até vem do Brasil: foi a Gilmar Mendes quem primeiro trouxe a público a suspeita de fraude numa recolha de assinaturas; fez com que se visse uma coisa a que antes ninguém tinha tinha prestado atenção.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, sim, estou a ver na net, e encontro vários exemplos de uso no Brasil, e até mesmo no sentido em que eu conheço a expressão. Vê comentário acima.

Comment: Mas é bem por aí mesmo

Comment: Bruno, eu costumo, as vezes, usar está expressão. "Não levante a lebre". Agora mesmo, vou usar a frase, no meu grupo de watsap do condomínio.